# Allow a page on specified time ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, time, limit

Is there an ASP.NET Script to allow a specific webpage to be access only in a specific time of the day in the week? for example: in a course you want your students to access your webpage in your network in a certain hour of the day and the week!
Update:Answer cannot be no.i have an example from a site:www.codeforces.com
In this site in specific time,contest is running and codeforces allows a page on that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `page_load` you could have something like this

```
if (!IsAllowedTime())
{
    Response.Redirect("/ComeBackLater.aspx");
}
```

Where within `IsAllowedTime` you would validate `DateTime.Now` against your time restrictions

Comment: Can a hacker skip this redirect?

Comment: @Sepehr Mohammadi: there is always a catch... but you're extremely safe.

Comment: :Thanks.if you have another solution,please reply.